# Beat detective clips move backwards

Tags: drums, daw

I've got a drumbeat and a 16th note triplet grid that is adequate to for this beat and the time signature is 4/4. For experiments I mark exactly one bar, and apply beat detective.

Then I set clip conform to 16th note triplets, press conform and watch everything go down the bin. It's not placing the the clips to the closest grid positions, but rather 1-3 grid positions backwards! Why could this be?

I've tried playing around with the markings, making sure that exactly one bar is marked from beat one to beat 3, and one bar + one beat and so but it isn't worked. If I would have made that algorithm I would have created it so that it would simply move the transients to the closest possible grid position. How is this software "thinking"?

Comment: I feel like using triplets in 4/4 is a mistake

Comment: Interesting problem, is beat detective finding the strong points in the drum beat? or is it displaced before then. If so maybe try a different intensity.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about the [Pro Tools Beat Detective](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/aug03/articles/protoolsnotes.htm)? Well I didn't use Pro Tools much, but I'll speak from my understanding of quantizers and electronic music.

It is really important with all music and certainly all programs even more so to keep the beat steady. If you slow down significantly, or even only slightly for quite a few bars, obviously the program will put you back a few beats as it can't tell if you meant the beat to be fast (like at the beginning) or slow (as you slowed down at the end).

That said, that probably isn't your problem, unless you are new to drums and have some trouble keeping a steady beat.

You mention that your beat is 16th triplets in 4/4 time - red flags! 4/4 is quadruple meter, and a simple meter. If you are doing constant triplets, not only intermittently, it may be you are confusing the beat for a *complex meter.* In that case, you could try changing to 12/8 time, which is the complex quadruple. 12/8 is friendly to all kinds of triplet nonsense. Of course changing the meter may require a bit of bar shifting to make it all align.

Those two errors are very common. Just comment if you had a slightly different problem. Again I am not familiar with the software, but no software currently exists that deals with those issues consistently.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your capture selection is looking at the right bars. In the selection box, check to see if beat detective doesn't think you are working with a different starting point or ending point. Does it all the time and then you get everything back or forward a bit